# Automated Post-billing Service/Solution

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, creditcard, payments

I'm trying to find a solution or service that will allow for my company to automatically take a customer's credit card information via the web to keep on file and bill against based on how much they have used the services we provide. We need a service that will also handle the payment processing as well.

Note that this is not recurring billing. The bill at the end of each month won't be the same.

Presently, we are having to take a customer's credit card information over the phone and manually input it into Quickbooks, but this just doesn't work for scalability. We will still be manually invoicing the customers, but we need automated credit card acceptance and storage without the liabilities involved with storing it on our own server.

Solutions that integrate with Wordpress would be a plus.

Comment: So you're trying to completely avoid handling the CC and other PII on your own site/servers or just outsource the storage component? If you outsource the storage only then your PCI-DSS requirements will be lowered, but you will still need to meet the requirements for handling credit card information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up going with Braintree

Comment: Yes, we don't want to have to store the credit card info ourselves, we just want to be able to charge against it. I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "hand the automated portion" though.

Comment: Not only did I mistype my comment but it was irrelevant to your answer. You can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spreedly](https://spreedly.com/), works for us for card payments! Alternatively if you're a UK company look at [Eazipay](http://www.eazipay.co.uk/) for an easy entrance to Direct Debit collection.

Comment: Spreedly looks pretty interesting and [might work for what we would like to do](https://spreedly.com/manual/integration-reference/adding-a-fee-to-a-subscriber)